# How to version ASP.NET MVC web application in git?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, git, version-control, gitignore

I have created an ASP.NET MVC 5.0 web application in Visual Studio 2015. I can see that there are a whole lot of files getting created. To version this project, what all are the files/directories do I need to commit in git? Which are to be excluded in .gitignore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule of thumb is not to version control binaries and user specific files such as `*.user`,  `*.lock.json`,`/bin`, `/obj`, `/packages`, folders.

You can use [VisualStudio.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) file from [this repository](https://github.com/github/gitignore).

Don't forget to rename it to `.gitignore`.

This file is maintained by the community and contains all the reasonable ignore settings for .NET applications.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add into repository webapp folder from your project, but you must to add in .gitignore file folders: bin & obj

Hope it helps;)